# Daisy CMS having trouble building

Tags: java, open-source, maven-2, build-process

after reading through the README.txt's throughout the entire SVN I have followed them but still am missing a few dependencies that are necessary for Fortify Sourceanalyzer to build.

these dependencies are

```
    DocumentEditorForm
    org.outerj.daisy.sync.AttributeType
    org.outerj.daisy.sync.SyncState
    org.outerj.daisy.sync.SystemState
```

I have also gone out and manually retrieved a lot of classes on my own that i hadn't been able to get with the maven build process.

I used maven1.1 as instructed and just ran

```
    maven
```

in the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

Those classes are defined in *daisy-sync-core*. I haven't found a repository that hosts that particular jar (it's not even on http://daisycms.org/maven).

You could try building Daisy yourself according to the [daisy README](http://svn.daisycms.org/repos/daisy/trunk/daisy/README.txt) and putting the jar into your local repository.